# Jira Plugin Framework comparison (OSGI/Pluggable solution)

Tags: spring, osgi, jira, apache-karaf, pluggable

I need to create an architecture that provides a scalable and flexible solution to allow future customizations in many aspects, as a 'plugin architecture' usually provides. Java is preferable so I'm now looking at Jira Plugin Framework, which is java based already supporting spring and OSGI and also a nice architecture itself. We can found it here: https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/atlassian-platform-common-components/plugin-framework/embedding-the-plugin-framework

It's nice to clear that I do not want to extend Jira itself. I need to turn my application as extensible as possible and I'm going to use Jira Plugin Framework as a base technology.

Anyone here has any experience with jira plugin framework and can provide me some guidelines? Do you even know other open source solutions to build pluggable and flexible architectures or any related technology stack in Java?